# How can i get Android type like ColorOs, Flyme, LineageOS, etc?

Tags: android, version

How can i get Android type like ColorOs, Flyme, LineageOS, etc programmatically? I looked at the android build class and could not find something useful.

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT //gives API level
android.os.Build.VERSION.BASE_OS //gives Android version
```

But this does not give me a clue if the app is running on a flyMe os, Color os, Lineage os, etc. I need to get the parameter as on the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I understand, that the required parameter exists only in respective OS-es and will be null in other Android builds.